# Produce a Stream out of the result of a previous finished Stream

Tags: rust

In Rust and with a Stream that produces `Vec<u8>`, how can I consume the result and build a new stream of `u8`?

For example a stream that looks like:

```
let a: Vec<Vec<u8>> = vec![vec![1,2,3], vec![4,5,6]];
let my_stream = futures::stream::iter(a);
```

I would like to consume and map it to end up with:

```
assert_eq!(vec![1,2,3,4,5,6], my_stream.collect::<Vec<_>>().await);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normally a job for `flatten`, but it expects the stream to produce other streams. You can add `.map(futures::stream::iter)` to adapt the inner vectors to streams, or combine both into a call to `flat_map`:

```
let my_stream = my_stream.flat_map(futures::stream::iter);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=66b73141dbe9d099920d581642de6902)